# Get error when combine two _Generic

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I want to combine two types in **C** for calling function (like multiply vector and matrix with different columns and rows):

```
#define CC_FIRST(a)        _Generic((a), int: int8d)
#define CC_SECOND(b)       _Generic((b), int: int16d)
#define CC_SP(first, second) first ## second
#define TEST(a,b) CC_SP(CC_FIRST(a), CC_FIRST(b)) (a,b)

int test1 = 10;
int test2 = 25;

TEST(10,25); // => int8dint16d(10,25), but not work
```

And have this:

> pasting ")" and "CC_FIRST" does not give a valid preprocessing token
>   #define TEST(a,b) CC_SP(CC_FIRST(a), CC_FIRST(b)) (a,b)
>
> expected identifier or '(' before '_Generic'
>   #define CC_FIRST(a)        _Generic((a), int: int8d)
>
> pasting ")" and "CC_FIRST" does not give a valid preprocessing token
>   #define TEST(a,b) CC_SP(CC_FIRST(a), CC_FIRST(b)) (a,b)
>
> 'int8d' undeclared (first use in this function)
>   #define CC_FIRST(a)        _Generic((a), int: int8d)
>
> expected ';' before '_Generic'
>   #define CC_FIRST(a)        _Generic((a), int: int8d)
>                               ^

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: _Generic is an operator, and it's evaluated **after** macro expansion

Comment: Compile with `-E` to see the preprocessor's interpretation of your code.

Comment: "_combine_ two types" is unclear.  Please provide an example.

Comment: what are you trying to do? What do you want `TEST(10, 25)` to do?

Answer (score 1):

`_Generic` is not at all what you seem to expect. In particular it is not evaluated by the preprocessor. The preprocessor knows nothing about types, but only about textual tokens. So concatenating `_Generic` and `()` of the previous part can never work, because they wouldn't form a valid token.

Comment: Thanks. Can I implement it by another way?

Comment: @wrazhevsky, your question is not precise enough to know what you really want to achieve. Please ask another one, where you tell us what you really want to do.